# mysql select one last row of each type

Tags: mysql, select

I got table with ID, TYPE, NUMBER, DATE

example, without date:

```
1 a 15
2 c 10
3 b 11
4 b 14
5 a 19
6 c 1
7 b 14
8 b 7
```

SELECT 1:

I want to select 1 last record of each type ... so result will be:

```
5 a 19 15.2.2014 16:00
8 b 7 15.2.2014 16:50
6 c 1 15.2.2014 17:00
```

NOW it is 15.2.2014 17:01

SELECT 2:

I want to select from "SELECT 1" maximum from each last type last 60 minutes (try to not to do it as "select from (SELECT 1)", result will be:

```
8 b 7 15.2.2014 16:50
```

can someone help me ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Some questions:   Is your `date` column a `DATETIME` data type?  In the result set you show under SELECT 1: how do you get `5 a 16` from your sample data (should it be `5 a 19`?  By *last* do you mean *having the most recent date*? Is your `ID` column an autoincrement column?  Do you ever `UPDATE` this table to change the `DATE` column, or do you only `INSERT` to it?  Believe it or not, all those questions are relevant to providing you an answer.

Comment: Would your second query not include `6 c 1 15.2.2014 17:00` ?

Comment: date is timestamp ... is result I got mistake, right is 5 a 19 ... ID is autoincrement column ... I do not make update .. I just only INSERT ... it is table for statistics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the first with this `exists` clause:

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.type = t.type and t2.date > t.date
                 );
```

The maximum in the last 60 minutes is the same as the maximum overall.  But to get records that are only from the last 60 minutes, add a `where` condition:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.date >= date_sub(getdate(), interval 1 hour) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.type = t.type and t2.date > t.date
                 );
```

Note that these queries assume you want the most recent row based on the `date` column.  You can do the same logic with the `id` column instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT id,type,date from table 
WHERE 
id in (SELECT max(id) FROM table GROUP BY type);
```

Comment: good solution for SELECT 1 ... the same as wrote user "G one"

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select *
from Table1
where id in (select max(id) from Table1 group by type)
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8c2a/3)

Comment: good solution for SELECT 1 ...

Answer (score -1):

you can do it with this with this query

```
(SELECT * FROM example WHERE type="a" ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM example WHERE type="b" ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1)
```

**EDIT**
This code is tested AND it works

Comment: Point taken, problem solved.

Comment: not useful for me ... I do not know how many type there will be